# Create new user with privileges in database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to implement a login feature in my project. In order to make it "secure" I whant to try to use the user system provided by phpmyadmin (my tool to manage my databases) rather than login in with the root user and then store usernames and passwords in a table and verify them etc.

I tried to add a new user in phpmyadmin and then I looked the SQL code that represented the code to add a new user :

```
CREATE USER 'username_test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '***';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'username_test'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `restaurant_app`.* TO 'username_test'@'localhost';
```

So my goal was to use this SQL to register-login users in my app. But I can't figure out how to provide the password, I don't fully understand the first part of this command. More over, I would like you to tell me if using the phpmyadmin user feature is a good idea or if I should use the classic way to do this : connect to the database using (user:"root", passwd:"") and look into my own table containing all the users logins ?

Comment: The answer to security-related question is *if you don't understand it, don't write it yourself*. For example, you can use Spring Security (even in a non-Spring project) to handle this for you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea. You can use bcrypt to store hashed passwords instead of plain text passwords. In the bacend you would hash the password that comes from the front-end and compare that value with the one in the database.

You can read [this](http://davismj.me/blog/bcrypt/) post to see some examples.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what I will try is to add a new user in phpmyadmin that can only modify one specified database not all. And then I will use this user in my connection to the database in my script to execute queries to verifiy login inputs from the users or even register new ones. I will also implement what is said in your link. I think it's the right way to go. I'm new to databases but I think I have a better understanding about how we should use them :D

Comment: I still think it's a really bad idea to use a db user as login for you app :P

Comment: my users logins will be stored in a table in my db, but to query and verify the inputs in my app I must use a db user to create a connection between my app and the db, right ?

Comment: Oh, I just understood what you meant. Yes, you use a db user to connect and execute queries, but it's not a user from your app. Your are correct